# There is empty list by using Selector(from parsel) or Etree.fromstring (from lxml) + requests.get

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, selector, elementtree

I want to get some data from a website. Just take one as an example url "http://op1.win007.com/Oddlist/1585369.htm" 
From this kind of website link to get the other links by using Xpath

However, I used requests/urllib2 to get the content and then I used Selector and Etree.html/fromstring. But the list is empty.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


z = requests.get(url,headers= headers) 
print z (result shows 200）
print z.text (result shows the html context, unicode style)
sel = Selector(text = z.text）
print sel (result shows <Selector xpath = None data = balabala> actually empty list)
sel2 = etree.Html or html.fromstring (z.content or z.text)
print sel2(result shows <Element html at balabala> another empty one
```

codes as shown as above

Next I want to use

```
url_2 = sel.xpath('//td[contains(@width,"56")]/@onclick')
```

to get the next step links.
But the sel is empty

Thank you so much 
This is my first time to use this website.
I have already tried three days and failed.
Hope a good news from you!

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: `print()` text which you get with `requests/urllib2` before you use `Etree` and see if there is your element.

Comment: I just double checked this link, it can work in chrome and safari but it seems not working well if you just click it in this page. So please paste it into chrome. Sorry about that~

Comment: is it working when you turn off JavaScript in browser ? request/urllib2 doesn't run JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks furas. I do not know how to set this question to "be solved". Although I did not finish this code I have already found what is the barrier for me. Actually the data is all shown by js just like you guessed. I have found the link by F12 or I will use selenium. Thank you so much.